# Contour integral using residue

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Assume that $f(z) \in \{\sqrt{2z^2 + 1}\}$ $,f(0) = 1$

We have a cut: $\gamma = \{|z| = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}, Re(z) \geqslant 0 \}$

$\oint\limits_{|z|=1} \frac{z dz}{(z+2)(f(z) + 3)}$

I found singularities: $z_1 = 2$ and $z_{2,3} = -2$. But they are not in our area $|z| < 1$. According to residue theorem, it's mean that integral is equal $0$.

But in book they have completely different answer: $\pi i( \frac{17}{12} - \sqrt2 )$

What have I missed?

Comment: $z_1=2$ is a singularity ? maybe $z_1=-2$, $z_{2,3}=-2$ ?

Comment: Careful with the branch cut for the square root. You have to avoid the cut in order to compute the contour integral properly!

Comment: Oh, yes,sorry for mistake. But it make no difference, isn't it? They are not in $|z| < 1$

Comment: @Acapello I agree with you, yet I don't understand what you call "the cut": are you "cutting off" the non-negative real axis (this much is clear)... **and also** the circle $\;|z|=\frac1{\sqrt2}\;$ ? How come, what for and how's that possible? This automatically would make our integration  domain non-connected, and I've no idea whatsoever how to carry on such an integration, though this may only be my ignorance.

Comment: I think the correct contour of integration is a keyhole contour with radius one and slits $[- i/\sqrt{2}, -i ]$, $[ i/\sqrt{2}, i]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment...

I would suggest:

1) Choose the contour of integration as described above, this means two half circles with radius  $1$ arguments $[\pm\pi/2\pm\epsilon]$ and four straight lines  $[\pm i/\sqrt{2}\pm\epsilon,\pm i\pm\epsilon]$. The litte circles around the branching point will vanish...

2)Because no residues are inside our contour the only contribution is from the branch cut integrals around the slits.

3)The remaining integrals can be done by flip the cut so that we just have one which reaches from $(-i/\sqrt{2},i\sqrt{2})$
(You have to be really careful about the arguments at this point)

4) The remaining integral can be done by reverting the direction of the contour and pick up the residues in the whole complex plane

5) At this point it will be necessary to pick up residues at infinity, this can be done by changing $f(z)\rightarrow \frac{-1}{z^2}f(1/z)$ and looking at $0$

Comment: http://cs622926.vk.me/v622926666/9cac/deLUjbUARJU.jpg

Comment: Sorry for bad describtion. That how our area should look like.

Comment: Pick up the residues in the whole complex plane? Maybe it will be the best way. I'll try to do it.

Comment: you can equally pick a straight line, this shouldn't matter... :)